# Inverse weighted average

Tags: weights, weighted-mean

Is there something like an "inverse weighted average"?

In my case, I have daily prices and daily units sold of a bunch of products and I would like to give prices with more units higher weights than prices with fewer units. How would I calculate the weights?

Comment: just weight by num of units

Comment: sorry I do not understand. I still want to end up with reasonable weighted prices

Comment: give an example of data and explain what you want

Comment: What @Aksakal suggested is mathematically the same thing as market capitalization weighting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization-weighted_index , for instance as used in the S&P 500 index.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, market cap like weighting would be to weight by a product of units sold and prices, i.e. the sales amount. i think he needs to weight by units sold, not sales amount, but it's not really clear what's his problem